# How to format difftime as hh:mm in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, difftime

I want to display difftime data with ggplot2 and I want the tick format to be `hh:mm`.

```
library(ggplot2)  

a= as.difftime(c("0:01", "4:00"), "%H:%M", unit="mins")
b= as.difftime(c('0:01', "2:47"), "%H:%M", unit="mins")

ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_point(shape=1) +    
                  scale_x_time(labels = date_format("%H:%M"), 
                               breaks = "1 hour")
```

But I get the following warning:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type difftime. Defaulting to continuous.
Warning message:
In structure(as.numeric(x), names = names(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

and this as a graph:
[image]

**Update:**
my example was too minimal, I also need to be able to display negative differences, so this would be better data:

```
a= as.difftime(c(-60, -4*60),  unit="mins")
b= as.difftime(c(-60, 2*60+47), unit="mins")
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_point(shape=1)
```

Comment: Some bad news: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1377

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer has two parts.

#### Plotting `difftime` objects

According to `help("scale_x_time")`, `ggplot2` supports three date/time classes: `scale_*_date` for dates (class `Date`), `scale_*_datetime` for datetimes (`class POSIXct`), and `scale_*_time` for times (class `hms`). The last one is what we need here.

Class `hms` is a custom class for `difftime` vectors. `as.hms()` has a method for `difftime`. So. `difftime` objects can be plotted with `ggplot2`  by coercing to class `hms`:

```
a <- as.difftime(c(-60, -4 * 60),  unit = "mins")
b <- as.difftime(c(-60, 2 * 60 + 47), unit = "mins")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = hms::as.hms(b), y = hms::as.hms(a))) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1)
```

[image]

Please, note that negative time differences are shown as well.

#### Formatting the tick labels

The OP has requested that tick marks should be labeled in `hh:mm` format. Apparently, the default formatting is `hh:mm:ss`. This can be modified by specifying a function that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output to the `labels` parameter of the `scale_x_time()` and `scale_y_time()` functions:

```
format_hm <- function(sec) stringr::str_sub(format(sec), end = -4L)
ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = hms::as.hms(b), y = hms::as.hms(a))) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  scale_x_time(name = "b", labels = format_hm) +
  scale_y_time(name = "a", labels = format_hm)
```

[image]

The `format_hm()` function truncates the `:ss` part from the default format. In addition, the axis are labeled nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your constraints, you might consider translating the difftimes to distinct datetimes, which ggplot can handle just fine:

```
library(lubridate)
a_date_times <- floor_date(Sys.time(), "1 day") + a
b_date_times <- floor_date(Sys.time(), "1 day") + b
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=a_date_times, y=b_date_times)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sadly my constraints require negative times e.g. `-1:00` while this solution would give me `23:00`

Answer (score 1):

My best approach so far is:

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(lubridate)

a= as.difftime(c(-60, -4*60),  unit="mins")
b= as.difftime(c(-60, 2*60+47), unit="mins")

xbreaks = seq(ceiling(min(b)/60), floor(max(b)/60)) * 60
ybreaks = seq(ceiling(min(a)/60), floor(max(a)/60)) * 60


ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_point(shape=1) + 
                  scale_x_continuous(labels = f, breaks = xbreaks) +
                  scale_y_continuous(labels = f, breaks = ybreaks)



f <- function(x){
  t = seconds_to_period(abs(x)*60)
  r = sprintf("% 2i:%02i", sign(x)*hour(t), minute(t))
  return(r)
}
```